# Filter JSON field from file

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath

I have a JSON file with some data on it, like the below one:

```json
{
    "84d0da32-c945-9844-86cc-4b4bd6100dc5": {
        "UUID": "84d0da32-c945-9844-86cc-4b4bd6100dc5",
        "GroupName": "TEST1",
        "EntryTitle": "host1",
        "Username": "sys",
        "NewPassword": "@PVmkiajauauajjhfz-5/NN"
    },
    "test": {
        "UUID": "5c3c162f-0a80-f949-85a0-afcf9aedb6c8",
        "GroupName": "TEST2",
        "EntryTitle": "host2",
        "Username": "sys",
        "NewPassword": "H7-uPz2mkaaua@ki7q?NSs?"
    }
}
```

I am trying to filter only the field `GroupName` or `EntryTitle`, with `json_query` but it always give `null`, if I try to write all `GroupName` field, it returns both.
I only want to pass for example if `GroupName` is `TEST2` return the `EntryTitle` field.

Example of my code until now:

```yaml
- name: load json data
  shell: cat entries.json
  register: result

- name: save json do var
  set_fact:
    jsondata: "{{ result.stdout | from_json }}"
- name: server name
  set_fact:
    servername: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jq) }}"
  vars:
    jq: "*.GroupName"
- name: Print
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    -  "{{ servername }}"
```

Comment: A good question would have included your trial that _"always give `null`"_ as you are claiming it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your trial at a query was something like

```
*[?GroupName == `TEST2`].EntryTitle
```

This does indeed returns an empty list (`[]`) as `*` is an [*object projection*](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#object-projections), and in order to chain a projection on top of another projection, in JMESPath, you have to reset the previous projection, with a [*pipe expression*](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions).

Here, the query `` [?GroupName == `TEST2`] `` is a [*filter projection*](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections), so you indeed have to follow the above mentioned rule by resetting the projection created by the *object projection*:

```
* | [?GroupName == `TEST2`].EntryTitle
```

So, you should update your `server name` task accordingly:

```yaml
- name: server name
  set_fact:
    servername: "{{ jsondata | json_query(jq) }}"
  vars:
    jq: "* | [?GroupName == `TEST2`].EntryTitle"
```

---

*Side notes:*

- *another good idea would be to use the purposed modules of Ansible rather than a `shell` task. If the file is on the remote node, use the [`slurp` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html), if the file is local to the controller, use a [`file` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_lookup.html)*
- *try to get the habit of using the [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html) syntax instead of the `with_*` one, already. There are plenty of examples to migrate them [in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) and the syntax usually feels more aligned across all different loops of your tasks, as the logic is expressed in filters rather than in the variation of the `with_*` used*

So, if the file is on the remote node(s):

```yaml
- slurp:
    src: entries.json
  register: entries_json

- debug:
    var: >-
      entries_json.content
        | b64decode
        | from_json
        | json_query('* | [?GroupName == `TEST2`].EntryTitle | [0]')
```

Would yield

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  ? |-
    entries_json.content
      | b64decode
      | from_json
      | json_query('* | [?GroupName == `TEST2`].EntryTitle | [0]')
  : host2
```

And if the file is on the controller node, then you can cut it down to a single task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      lookup('ansible.builtin.file', 'entries.json')
        | from_json
        | json_query('* | [?GroupName == `TEST2`].EntryTitle | [0]')
```

Would yield

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  ? |-
    lookup('ansible.builtin.file', 'entries.json')
      | from_json
      | json_query('* | [?GroupName == `TEST2`].EntryTitle | [0]')
  : host2
```

*Extra note: the `| [0]` is once again a pipe expression meant to reset the previous projection, as explained before, in order to get the element `[0]`, so the first one, of the JSON array.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to pick the field, the error was the projection you mention. I was trying to pick the value to build a sql command to be executed on every database to change password.s. To execute the sql command if the host is running is the same on json field if not skip and proceed to next one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. Your code works as expected. Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/entries.json 
{
    "84d0da32-c945-9844-86cc-4b4bd6100dc5": {
        "UUID": "84d0da32-c945-9844-86cc-4b4bd6100dc5",
        "GroupName": "TEST1",
        "EntryTitle": "host1",
        "Username": "sys",
        "NewPassword": "@PVmkiajauauajjhfz-5/NN"
    },
    "test": {
        "UUID": "5c3c162f-0a80-f949-85a0-afcf9aedb6c8",
        "GroupName": "TEST2",
        "EntryTitle": "host2",
        "Username": "sys",
        "NewPassword": "H7-uPz2mkaaua@ki7q?NSs?"
    }
}
```

read the file

```yaml
    - command: cat /tmp/entries.json
      register: result
```

and convert the *result* from JSON. Declare the variable

```yaml
  jsondata: "{{ result.stdout|from_json }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  jsondata:
    84d0da32-c945-9844-86cc-4b4bd6100dc5:
      EntryTitle: host1
      GroupName: TEST1
      NewPassword: '@PVmkiajauauajjhfz-5/NN'
      UUID: 84d0da32-c945-9844-86cc-4b4bd6100dc5
      Username: sys
    test:
      EntryTitle: host2
      GroupName: TEST2
      NewPassword: H7-uPz2mkaaua@ki7q?NSs?
      UUID: 5c3c162f-0a80-f949-85a0-afcf9aedb6c8
      Username: sys
```

The filter *json_query*

```yaml
  jq: "*.GroupName"
  servername: "{{ jsondata|json_query(jq) }}"
```

gives the list of the attribute GroupName values

```yaml
  servername:
  - TEST1
  - TEST2
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    jsondata: "{{ result.stdout|from_json }}"
    jq: "*.GroupName"
    servername: "{{ jsondata|json_query(jq) }}"

  tasks:

    - command: cat /tmp/entries.json
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: jsondata
    - debug:
        var: servername
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i localhost, pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  jsondata:
    84d0da32-c945-9844-86cc-4b4bd6100dc5:
      EntryTitle: host1
      GroupName: TEST1
      NewPassword: '@PVmkiajauauajjhfz-5/NN'
      UUID: 84d0da32-c945-9844-86cc-4b4bd6100dc5
      Username: sys
    test:
      EntryTitle: host2
      GroupName: TEST2
      NewPassword: H7-uPz2mkaaua@ki7q?NSs?
      UUID: 5c3c162f-0a80-f949-85a0-afcf9aedb6c8
      Username: sys

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  servername:
  - TEST1
  - TEST2

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```